# Can you use the same ID with different element types in CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I know this is invalid HTML:

```
<p id="sally">paragraph</p>
<p id="sally">paragraph</p>
```

Is this also invalid?

```
<div id="sally">
  <p id="sally">sally paragraph, inside of sally div</p>
  <p>paragraph with nothing special.</p>
</div>
```

and something like

```
div.#sally{
  width: 90%;
  height: 3em;
  padding: 20px;
}
p.#sally{
  font-size: 1em;
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: Why would you not just use classes?

Comment: No, its not. IDs are meant to be unique.

Comment: No you cannot do that. IDs are unique regardless of the element they are applied to

Comment: It's possible, it's *not* valid in the HTML but *is* valid in the CSS if you remove the `.` from `div.#sally` and `p.#sally`, and in practice it would work in most browsers. https://jsfiddle.net/nte2237s/2/

Comment: rephrased, code format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know this is invalid HTML

Correct

> Is this also invalid?

Yes. An ID must be unique in the document. Not unique per type in the document.

(That won't stop browser error recovery from sometimes giving you the result you are trying to achieve, but you should not depend on that).

> and something like

You can't use `.#`. A `.` starts a class selector. A `#` starts an ID selector.

You can have

```
div#sally { ... }
p#sally { ... }
```

And then have two different documents, one with a div with that ID and one with a paragraph with that ID, but both of which `<link>` to the same stylesheet.

If you want to identify two things are being in a group, then use a class. That is what class is for.

Answer (score 1):

No, it won't work because that is the purpose of ID--to be unique in the document. They made classes available so you can use the same style several times.

Answer (score 0):

```css
div#a {
  background-color: red;
}

span#a {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">Hello</div>
<span id="a">world</span>
```

I do not at all recommend this, as classes are a much better way of handling things. However, as a proof of a concept, this can indeed be done with CSS.

Comment: CSS selectors of `div#a` and `span#a` are valid, and although repeated ids in the same html document are *not* valid in practice they will work with the aforementioned `div#a` and `span#a` selectors. (Works in FF, Chrome and IE.)  https://jsfiddle.net/nte2237s/2/